# png showing back ground not background image

Tags: html, css, image, background, png

I have multiple layers and I am having trouble getting them to work out correctly.

The main background for my website is black #000000.

I then have a div with a background image which sits nicely centered on my black background.

Now I want to overlay my logo which is a PNG image file with a transparent background over the image which I mentioned above.

I thought this would be easy, but the result I am getting is my logo with a black box around it over the image.

Why is the transparency going down two layers to my background *color* rather than down one layer to my background *image*?

Comment: Can you provide a little code and/or a jsfiddle or something?  Or code + screenshot?

Comment: Actually it sounds like something has screwed up the transparency of your logo. PNG's will show a black background rather than transparent if saved incorrectly. You can also see the same thing by copying a PNG from the web and pasting it directly into Photoshop. I am pretty sure if you change your main background colour to red you'll find your logo still has a black background.

Comment: Are you assigning a black background color to the div containing the background image as well as the main background?

Comment: I tried the red thing and the box goes red so it is picking up the background image.

Comment: I only have the black background color in the body{} and *{}. Here is another question why do I have to put the color in both. If I delete either the background goes to white.

Comment: body{
 background-color:#000000;
 text-align:center;
 margin:auto;
 width:1100px;
 } 
 
 *{ 
 background-color:#000000;
 margin: auto;
 text-align:center;
 color:#ffffff;
 }
#page{
 width:900px;
 height:550px;
 padding:0;
 border-style:solid;
 overflow:hidden;
 }
.home{
 background-image:url('images/collections/spring_2013_couture/aster_opac.png');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 }

Comment: <div class=home>
<img src="images/logo/logo_white.png" width="800">
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Try using z-index:n where n is 0,1,2,-1